# setting string as extra-var in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am wondering why string as an extravar is not working and as a number its working in the following output. It can be observed that `foo` is an extravar but it only works when number is passed and when I passed `hi` it failed.

when string is passed as extra-var:

```
ansible-playbook  fail.yml -e foo='hi'
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [sample : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hi": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

When number is passed as extra-var:

```
 -->ansible-playbook  fail.yml -e foo=1
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [sample : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "1": "1"
}
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0


 -->cat fail.yml
---

- hosts: localhost

  roles:
    - sample

 -->cat sample/tasks/main.yml
---
# tasks file for sample
#
- debug: var={{ foo }}
```

Comment: See [Passing variables on the command line](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) Correct quotation `ansible-playbook  fail.yml -e "foo=hi"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `debug: var=` you do not need to the braces, just the variable name.

Change your tasks file to:

```
- debug: var=foo
```

Comment: extra-vars should get available to roles right ? I do not need to pass them from include_role ?

Comment: @monk: See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) "`extra vars (always win precedence)`".

Comment: Yes extra vars will be passed to roles. Your main issue was just that syntax error specifying the variable in the debug task